# Framer motion not rendering exit animation when using AnimatePresence and React HOC

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, framer-motion

In my attempt to create reusable animated HOC in React, I'm coming an issue rendering exit animations. It seems that AimatePresence does not register the exit animation and React just removes the component from the DOM without rendering the exit animation.

**The code of the HOC**

```
const withDropdown = (Component: React.ComponentType) => (props: InfoProps) =>
  (
    <div className="">
      <button> ... button element controls state </button>
      <AnimatePresence>
        {props.collapsed && (
          <motion.div
            key="modal"
            className="overflow-hidden"
            initial={{ height: "auto"}}
            animate={{ height: "auto" }}
            exit={{ height: 0 }}
          >
            <Component />
          </motion.div>
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>
    </div>
  );
```

**Code of the component**

```
const someInfo = () => {
  return (
    <motion.div className="flex flex-col">
      <p>Some Info </p>
    </motion.div>
  );
};
```

**Code inside my main component**

```
  const [showThis, setShowThis] = useState(false);
  const InfoWithDropDown = withDropdown(someInfo);
```

**JSX**

```
 <InfoWithDropDown
            collapsed={showThis}
            collapsedSetter={setShowThis}
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this quite easily after some trial and error.

The solution is to have the component manage its own state instead of passing the state and the setter down.

The new code for the HOC looks like this:

```
const withDropdown = (Component: React.ComponentType) => (props: InfoProps) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="mt-5">
      <button ... button to control state </button>
      <AnimatePresence>
        {isActive && (
          <motion.div
            key={props.value}
            className="overflow-hidden"
            initial={{ height: 0 }}
            animate={{ height: "auto" }}
            exit={{ height: 0 }}
          >
            <Component />
          </motion.div>
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>
    </div>
  );
};
```